# Notificar ao votar para fechar perguntas muito novas

Tags: novo-recurso, fechamento

### Motivação:

É muito comum que uma pergunta muito recente seja rapidamente votada e fechada. O problema disso é que é bastante comum se postar uma pergunta e logo em seguida aperfeiçoar ela. E também, o processo de fechamento é bastante traumático para que está iniciando no site. O ideal é, sempre que a pergunta for "recuperável", postar apenas um comentário pedindo mais detalhes ou explicando o problema. É de bom tom aguardar algum tempo até que o usuário tenha oportunidade de responder ao comentário ou melhorar a publicação.

### Recurso:

Sempre que alguém votar para fechar uma pergunta muito nova (digamos, menos que 30 minutos), mostrar a seguinte notificação:

[image: notificacao]

A ideia é fazer o votante refletir se o voto é realmente necessário naquele momento e se a pergunta merece ser sumariamente fechada. Claro que não se deve impedir o voto, apenas notificar. Acredito que isso por si só seja suficiente para reduzir bastante o número de fechamentos precoces.

Comment: Algum exemplo específico para *"o processo de fechamento é bastante traumático para quem está iniciando no site"?* Ou então exemplos de *"fechamento precoce"?*

Comment: @brasofilo Um exemplo: [Visualização de PDF em iframe](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/10505/visualizacao-de-pdf-em-iframe). A pergunta foi feita e em menos de uma hora já estava fechada. Foi editada e melhorada para um estado aceitável, mas jáz esquecida.

Comment: Os 30 minutos não teriam sido suficientes... acho que ainda está vaga a pergunta, faltaria o código PHP que a autora menciona. E, de todos modos, recebeu duas respostas, aceitou uma delas, não vejo onde está o trauma... Acho que o problema principal é que os novatos não sabem como funciona o sistema de mensagens aqui dentro; não há emails avisando "tem um **comentário** na sua pergunta"; e normalmente é importante estar presente nesses exatos 30/60 minutos que é quando comentários importantes são feitos. A pessoa acha que é igual um fórum, posta um troço e depois volta pra ver no que deu...

Comment: @brasofilo Nesse caso que se aumente o prazo para uma hora. O ponto é evitar fechar perguntas muito rápido sem dar oportunidade de reação antes. Como você mesmo afirmou, os novatos demoram mais de notar os comentários justamente por não entender o sistema ainda. De qualquer forma um email é enviado depois de algum tempo sem a pessoa abrir o site, não tenho certeza, acho que três horas.

Comment: Só uma correção na mensagem: "Esta pergunta foi criada **há** pouco tempo...". Mas não precisa refazer a imagem :)

Comment: O problema que pode acarretar isso é respostas vagas e talvez até [erradas](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/12795/7210). Poderia isso sim, bloquear a opção de responder, mas ai já seria alterar a forma de funcionamento do site.
Embora eu ache que se deva primeiro tentar ajudar o utlizador, mas pode acontecer como [nesta pergunta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/16396/7210) em que ficou arruinada por se ter deixado aberta demasiado tempo. O que até poderia ser uma boa pergunta se devidamente editada passou para uma pergunta baseada em opiniões e demasiado amplas, assim como a pergunta.

Comment: Exatamente @JorgeB. , colocar a pergunta [em suspenso] é uma proteção contra respostas "palpite". Acho que fechamento rápido não é uma punição nem tampouco um estado permanente. Tenho uma dúvida, e gostaria de ver números: qual a quantidade de coisas que entrou em fechamento *e não foi fechada*, e a quantidade de coisas que entrou em reabertura *e não foi reaberta*. Provavelmente pouco, quase nada.